# OpenMP nested parallel regions way slower than expected

Tags: openmp

On a ccnuma system with 4 nodes and 128 cores, i am calculating a sparse matrix - vector product.

Below are two different omp setups, version 1 just creates 128 threads and spreads them among the nodes, version 2 first creates a thread per node, calculates the range of rows to work on for each node and then creates 32 threads on each node to work on the respective range of rows.

The idea of the second version was that all threads on a node write into a contiguous range of the result vector y.

I set the `OMP_PLACES` environment variable to specify 4 places corresponding to the 4 nodes and verified that omp binds the threads to the expected nodes/cpus with `numa_node_of_cpu(cpu)` (from numactl) and `sched_getcpu()`. The outer region correctly binds one thread to each node, the inner region binds the threads to cpus in the node of the master thread.

Version 1 performs reasonably well, version 2 however is about 100x slower and *i don't know why*.

Overall speed is better when first copying input data to each node and making sure each thread works on the dataset in its local memory domain, the speed difference between both versions persists thogh.

For version 2, support for nested parallel regions was enabled with `omp_set_nested(1)`

As pointed out in comments, dynamic/guided scheduling is not ideal, however i also tried static scheduling, that resulted in worse performance (~70%) compared to guided, even though each matrix row has the same number of non-zero entries and each loop iteration has the same workload.

```c
int *row_idx = ...;
int *col_idx = ...;
double *val = ...;
double *y = ...;
double *x = ...;
int num_rows = ...;

// version 1 
// spawn 128 threads and distribute them on the nodes
#pragma omp parallel proc_bind(spread) num_threads(128)
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(guided, 512)
    for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        double temp = 0;
        for(int j = row_idx[i]; j < row_idx[i + 1]; j++){
            temp += val[j] * x[col[j]];
        }
        y[i] = temp;
    }
}

// version 2
omp_set_nested(1)
// spawn 4 threads, one on each numa node
#pragma omp parallel proc_bind(spread) num_threads(4)
{
    // calculate row range to work on
    int id = omp_get_thread_num()
    int start = nRows / 4 * id;
    int end = start + (nRows / 4);
    // spawn 32 threads on each node
    #pragma omp parallel proc_bind(master) num_threads(32)
    {
        #pragma omp for schedule(guided, 512)
        for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
            double temp = 0;
            for(int j = row_idx[i]; j < row_idx[i + 1]; j++){
                temp += val[j] * x[col[j]];
            }
            y[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nesting is generally inefficient and poorly supported. It tends to cause more issues than it solves. OpenMP tasks can now be used to replace nesting in many applications. That being said, it is still not easy to control the scheduling on NUMA systems so it is efficient. Did you bound thread to core yourself? Did you specify the nesting configuration to OpenMP? Did you check the threads are correctly bound to cores the way you think they are? I do not expect OpenMP runtimes to "spawn 4 threads, one on each numa node" correctly by default with nesting.

Comment: By the way, `schedule(guided, 512)` is not NUMA-friendly because of the dynamic scheduling. A runtime might consider NUMA-nodes during the scheduling but I do not expect it to do. I advise you to use static scheduling as much as possible on NUMA systems. If you need to balance the work, then things will be much more complex. OpenMP barely provide features for NUMA system. Some features like affinity hints have only been added recently to the standard and are not yet well supported by all implementations.

Comment: I set up OMP_PLACES environment variable to define 4 places corresponding to the 4 nodes. Also checked at runtime that omp binds the threads to the correct cpus (which turned out to be the case). Nesting was enabled with omp_set_nested(1). I have also tried static scheduling, but that resulted in ~70% of the performance with guided, even tho each matrix row has the same number of non-zero entries and each loop iteration should have the same workload.

Comment: (I'll add those details to the question in a bit)

Comment: Did you check numerically that the results are the same, just to rule out obvious errors?

Comment: Why `proc_bind(master)`? Doesn't that load all threads on one numa node?

Comment: Proc_bind(master) binds threads to the same place as the master thread. Since the thread that encounters a parallel region becomes it's master threads and the 4 threads that encounter the inner region are each on a different place/node

Comment: As for the numerical result, yes it's the same

Comment: Isn't the virtual cores interleaved in the NUMA configuration? i.e. thread 0 belongs to socket 0, thread 1 to socket 1, thread 2 to socket 2, thread 3 to socket 3, **thread 4 to socket 0**... ?

Comment: Just checked with numactl -H, If numactl can be trusted, its interleaved in blocks of 16 (e.g. 0-15 on node 1, 16-31 on node 2, etc.)